# How to make a web link for a java web application?

Tags: java, hyperlink, for-loop

I have developed a project in Netbeans web application and it is running fine. I want it to run this appication in another machine or system without copying the code.That means i need to run **with the URL** of the java script page.

For this i have changed the IP address and tried in other machine,In this case the same output page (whatever i executed in my machine) is coming in the other machine also.

But it has to take the other machine's input and then the corresponding output page should come..How to do this?? Wot are the possible changes i can do ?? Suggestions are most welcome..!!

Hope u understand my ques..!! thnks in advance !!

Comment: `Hope u understand my ques..!!` *NO*

Comment: (1)Java != JavaScript, (2)You want to access the web-application from other machines or you want to deploy the application on other machine?, (3) What are the output and input?

Comment: @Nishant: My input of the project is the folder of images.When i tried running with the url in other machine, the same image wotevr i have taken in my machine has been displayed, instaed of taking the new input from the other machine. for ur 2nd question i need both the answers...How can i deploy on pther machine,also how can i access my web appln in other machine....

Comment: I believe what you're trying to achieve is that you've got your web-app running on a server. It resolves some images from a directory on the server machine. Now, you want the server to resolve image files from a client machine. however, you thought that the client's directory structure when resolved locally on the server would **magically** yield the client's files?

Comment: @anirvan: OOps..!! Not clear with ur last part of question.... well.... i wanted to access my web application from other system.how can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, so next time try not to abbreviate and be more precise in your question. The more precise your question is, the more precise our answer can be.

IF I understand correctly, you want to be able to access your web-app from another computer via the internet (URL)? Or through your local network?

If you want to run it off the web, then I think you need to create a webpage, embed the app and upload the page to a server (in order to access it online). For a home network, put it in a shared folder and make sure it has readable/executable properties, then just type in the location (e.g. C:/Documents and Settings/Jane Doe/javaApp.jar) in the browser address bar.

If you want to just be able to have access to it anywhere, just send it to yourself in an email attachment or upload the file somewhere you readily have access to over the internet.

Hope that helps?