# How to access web application from other system?

Tags: java, web-applications

How can I access a java web application from other system..?? Please guide me how to do? i need it ASAP..

Some of my code:

```
<body> 
<form action="NewServlet" method="post" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg" >
.........................//
<br><br>
<tr> <td>Image Link: </td> 
<td> <input type="file" name="select" > </td> </tr> 
.........................//few other lines 
</body>
```

Comment: Not enough details. What is 'other system'?

Comment: Easy just install it on the other system, install java (sun.com) and you are cooking with gas :)

Comment: @jason.. No.. I want to run the project with the URL i.e.without copying the code into the second system.

Comment: Possibly duplication of your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000709/how-to-make-a-web-link-for-a-java-web-application

Comment: You have already got the answer by the comment of @anirvan in your other question. If you still don't understand it could be because of the english.

Comment: @gigadot:i replied him tat i'm not clear vth his answer.Let me know if u got somethng form his reply..I 'll be hapy..!!

Comment: ooh, ASAP, thats gonna sparkle the motivation :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Deploy your Java Web Application on other machine. *[You can use `.war` file this way servlet and java code is not needed to be copied on server machine.]*
2. Run the server.
3. Now on any machine other than the machine where you deployed your application you can access your application by hitting the url `http://[deployed-machine-ip]:[port]/[App-Name]`.

Comment: @Harry joy : Hey tanQ...but i tried this ya... But the same output screen is cmg i.e whatevr my last executed output page is there,this is only appearing on the second machine also.. It is not taking the second machine's input( input is folder of images according to my project)

Comment: @Deeps: where is your image folder? Under project `.war` or outside project?

Comment: @Deeps Did you write the web application? Are you sure it working?

Comment: @Harry joy: My images will be in system folder(C:\\Drive).I am inputting them by "input tag" in jsp page.

Comment: @Deeps: Will you please post some of your JSP code so we can clearly understand it?

Comment: @Deeps how do you access it from other machine? using web browser? If it works on one web browser, it should work for all unless the html is specific to the type of web broswer you use, e.g. IE, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: @Harry joy:<body>

    <form action="NewServlet" method="post" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg" ><br><br><tr>
        <td>Image Link: </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="select" >
        </td>
      </tr> .........................//few other lines </body>

Comment: @gigadot: The web appication is running perfectly in my system and if i change the Ipaddress(instead of localhost) it is working in other system also.But my problem is when i am running in other machine it is not taking the input images from the (second machine) system folder...Instead,whatever is ter in my machine same output is cmg..

Comment: @Deeps, you cannot access local folder from web application. You need to upload them to server. The other question you posted has aleady made clear about this.

Comment: @gigadot,@Deeps: I think he takes path to file as input which can be from any machine. If this is the case then @Deeps first you need to upload it to server before using it anywhere else.

Comment: web application isn't an executable jar. You cannot run it locally.

Comment: @Harry Joy,@gigadot: Yes,i am taking the input images from a system folder(as a path),these images will go to server side and receivs thru servlet.

Comment: @Deeps: okay. Now first you have to save your image on server either temporary or permanent and then access it where ever you want it to be processed. Are you able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can get a grip of what your problems are after the conversions.

First of all you need to understand how web application and web browser work.

The web browser generates a HTTP GET request to server, server, e.g. tomcat, generates a html page and send it back to your web browser. That's a complete operation. Now you can see your rendered html on your web broswer.

On your page, you may have a form which can takes the file or text as its field. Once you submit the request by htting a button, the form is generally converted into HTTP POST request and send to server. If the POST contains file, your server will need to save the file stream before you can run a process on the file.

If you submit a path to a folder on your local machine through your web broswer, it is impossible for web application to gain access to that folder since it is a security risk. You will need to upload the contents of the folder to web application and process it on server. However, once they are processed, they will be on server and your local contents will not be changes. You will have to provide links for them to download the processed files back to their local machine. There is no way for the local files get changes through web broswer.

If this is not clear enough, let me know.

Comment: tanQ !! but i knew this concept!! I also faced it for other web appln project.. but i am able to access the images from the system folder for this(even though this is also a web application). Well..Consider that I copied my images to a webapplication folder and gave them as input to my project.I can able to run the project which works fine.    So according to my problem,will i able to run it from other machine or not??(with the url,without copying the code into the other system).

Comment: You have a weapp on machine A and you copy image B on machine A to webapp folder on A? then you process image B in the webapp fodler? the image B get processed? I can see no problem if those are the steps. But if you have image on machine C, you will need to upload the image D to webapp and your webapp save it to webapp folder on A as image E. Now you can process image E to image G. The image G should be on server A. What else do you need? Do you need E to be sent back to machine C and replace image D? that's impossible via web browser.

Comment: Ok,tanks for the explanation..!! so the reason for this is that"webappln cannot access the system folders" is this?? cause i should be clear vth on wot basis this can't be done in webappln and where can be done?? any idea??

Comment: Use client-server method, i.e. write a client to upload and download them. Don't use web browser. You cannot write to local file using html or javascript. The only thing that you can do if you insist on using web browser is to use Flash. P.S. Please do not use words like "vth", "tanQ' on stack overflow. you are supposd to ask question is professional manner. I have hard time interpreting your english.

Comment: Or embed a signed applet in you web page but you still need the client-server pattern no matter what.